# Excel 2016 Userform Textbox Properties

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, userform

I'm having an issue with the Userform Textbox properties. I'm trying to write a simple sub to change the color of a textbox to gray when it is disabled. The code I'm attempting to write (which works on other VB Forms outside of Excel) is:

```
Private Sub ColorTxtBoxDisable(txtSel As TextBox)
    txtSel.BackColor = Color.Gray
End Sub
```

Where txtSel is an argument accepting a Textbox control name. However, declaring a variable/argument as Textbox brings up an entirely different set of properties available through the code, and Backcolor is not one of them. I've had no trouble changing textbox properties like this in other VB Forms, but Excel doesn't want to cooperate. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: You have to use `Msforms.textbox`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`txtSel` is an argument accepting a `TextBox` control. Not its name. It's an object reference, where `TextBox` is a type defined in whatever first referenced type library that contains a `TextBox` type, since it's unqualified. Since Excel is the host application, it takes precedence over the MSForms type library, which defines the `TextBox` control you mean to be using. Thus, VBA resolves that `TextBox` to `Excel.TextBox`, and that's not the textbox you're looking for.

> [image]
>
> <sub>The VBA standard library and the host application object model library can't be moved down or un-referenced.</sub>

Qualify the type with the library it's from. And pass it `ByVal` while you're at it, since there's no reason to (implicitly) pass it `ByRef` here.

```
Private Sub ColorTxtBoxDisable(ByVal txtSel As MSForms.TextBox)
```

Comment: Thank you!!  I knew it was something like that, but couldn't figure out how to get around it for the life of me.